# How to wish Stack Exchange a Merry Christmas?

Tags: discussion

I think the title says it all, from New Zealand- Merry Christmas all.

Comment: You should know better than to abuse the site by posting non-questions as questions.

Comment: @nobody - don't be a Grinch, merry Christmas!

Comment: Question presupposes that everyone celebrates Christmas, or that if they do, they don't celebrate the Orthodox Christmas (which is in January)

Answer (score 3):

Merry Christmas from Samoa, alofa atu iā te 'outou 'uma.